# show PDF absolute URL in Views table

Tags: views, uri, files

I've got a column of links to files in a table. They're displayed via file-fields with  'Output this field as a link" enabled in *Rewrite Results*. It's works great with fx images but width pdf's the table only shows the filename, not the path to it.

Any ideas on how to always show the complete path to a file no matter the file type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In views Change the **Formatter**  of the field from *Generic file*
   to *URL to file*.
2. Go to *REWRITE RESULTS* and check 'Output this field as link' and
   use replacement pattern of the file field.
3. check Use absolute path to get absolute path link of the file

That's it you will get complete path of the file instead of file name at output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but the URL to File formatter isn't available in my field, only 'rendered file, image, image link formatter'. I've used 'rendered file'.

Comment: Drupal: 7.24 & views: 7.x-3.7

Comment: @KristofferRom I think you don't have Entity API module enabled right.I think that might be the problem

Comment: it is enabled I'm afraid. I've just discovered that the field isn't actually a https://drupal.org/project/filefield but an imagefield accepting PDFs too. Could that be the issue? If so, any way to convert the fields without loosing all the content in them?

Comment: @KristofferRom I wonder, if its an image field it's not possible to upload pdf files even if add 'pdf'in Allowed file extensions. Can you please check it once.

Comment: it is possible and on the website pfd's are clickable and loading in a new window as intended. But I need the full URL displayed so users can access PDFs via the excel export too. thanks for your time, really appreciate it

Comment: I've tested the filefield approach you suggested. It works - so maybe I should just delete that image field and migrate the files the hard way - one node at a time?

Comment: Good point, done (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115839/field-migration-image-field-to-file-field)